# CGPoint(_,_) Requiring CGFloat Inputs on Linux

Tags: linux, swift

My Swift code runs fine in Xcode on my Mac, but when I deploy to my third-party Cloud hosting service built for server-side Swift I run into this problem.  I am getting the error: `Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'CGFloat'` when using `CGPoint(x: Int, y: Int)`. I would rather use an integer over a float.

[image]

I believe that this is an issue with Swift specifically on Linux.  In addition to this question, are there anyways to debug Swift on a Mac, but for a Linux environment? Also, what other inconsistencies does Swift for Linux have? I have found that arc4random is not supported and that Dispatch needs to be imported for any dispatch related code.

Comment: Please restrict the question to a *single* problem ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux (and other non-Apple platforms),
`CGPoint` is defined in [NSGeometry.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/NSGeometry.swift) as part of the
[swift-corelibs-foundation](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation) project.

As one can see in the source code, there is no initializer taking `Int` parameters, so you have to convert them explicitly:

```
let xVal: Int = ...
let yVal: Int = ...

let point = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(xVal), y: CGFloat(yVal))
```